# useQuery with tRPC wont recieve my query input

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-typescript, trpc.io

I am new to tRPC and react-query. I've been working to test .query (BE) and useQuery (FE) and I tried to pass data from FE to BE. However, since TS is a static typing, I get compile error although the code is working (it's working smoothly if I change to JS).

Here's my BE

```
export const appRouter = trpc
  .router()
  .query("greet", {
    input: z
      .object({
        name: z.string().nullish(),
      })
      .default({ name: "World" }),
    resolve({ input }) {
      return {
        message: `Hello ${input.name?.toUpperCase()}!`,
      };
    },
  })
```

and my FE is calling it by

```
const greet = trpc.useQuery(["greet", { name: "Maria" }]);
```

The compile error is on the { name: "Maria" } part.

It says "Type '{ name: string; }' is not assignable to type 'null | undefined'.ts(2322)". I don't know why the useQuery type definition
[is like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvJbA.png) Which I think I can't pass any parameters at all(?)

Please help, I have no idea. Thanks for reading and answering my question :)

Comment: You may want to include the [trpc.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trpc.io) tag, so others can find this in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little bit of update, I have resolved this problem by moving to a new repo, lol.

I think the problem is possibly caused by

Possibility 1: The undefined createReactQueryHooks in the "trpc" so you need to specify `const trpc = new createReactQueryHooks<AppRouter>();` with the AppRouter being the appRouter type you export from the BE. Don't do `const trpc = new createReactQueryHooks();` with "any" type.

Possibility 2: Your javascript and typescript package overlaps, so the compiler might mistakenly detect the javascript one which most of them do not specify type.

Comment: That should be `const trpc = new createReactQueryHooks<AppRouter>();` the convention is to [capitalize the type name](https://github.com/peerreynders/trpc-minimal-web/blob/91cb31cdb055038faba8ac6cbd0ba8a517e01ec2/src/server/app-router.ts#L25) as in `export type AppRouter = typeof appRouter;` while `appRouter` is the actual router used by the server.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the correction! Was just writing based on memorization without checking the code.

Comment: @MariaKhelli Are you using trpc v9 or v10 though. It's not clear from the docs whether the createReactQueryHooks is still needed in v10

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the .nullish part and adding a ':' after resolve like this:

```js
export const appRouter = trpc
  .router()
  .query("greet", {
    input: z
      .object({
        name: z.string().,
      })
      .default({ name: "World" }),
    resolve: async ({ input }) => {
      return {
        message: `Hello ${input.name?.toUpperCase()}!`,
      };
    },
  })
```

I am also quite new to trpc so i'm sorry if this doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem and been poking and prodding it for two days.

Turns out it goes away once you set [`strict`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strict) to `true` in the `tsconfig.json` under [`compilerOptions`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#compilerOptions)

The fragility of the TypeScript tool-chain never ceases to amaze me.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this issue on VSCODE. Quitting VS code, and  reopening the project solved this (it also then properly showed any underlying issues).